# Manage Databases without CloudKit Dashboard?

Tags: ios, cloudkit

I would like use CloudKit without CloudKit Dashboard.

Could I have diffulculties or other during my development?

Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of things that you can only do from the dashboard. You can use your app to create recordTypes with fields, but if you want to index fields and make them queryable, then you need to do that from the dashboard. You also need the dashboard to migrate your data structure to production.

Comment: Thank you Edwin ! If I can't have fields queryable, it's completely useless.

Comment: You also have to be aware, that you can only make new fields and recordTypes on development. You have to migrate the data structure to production using the dashboard

Answer (score 1):

What are you trying to do? This is like asking if you can develop an app with Xcode, but not use the debugger. It's possible, but why would you want to avoid a tool that helps make your job easier?

CloudKit was designed so that you could start writing code and using the database right away without needing to configure anything in the dashboard. However, at some point you're going to need to move to production or tweak the schema in your container and you're going to need the dashboard for that.

Comment: Sorry for not replying sooner. I've an issue with Cloudkit. I can't access the Cloudkit DashBoard although the other team members can to do it. From my perspective, I would like to have  other possibilities to manage databases without using exclusively  Cloukit Dashboard.